# thread safety in java with an external API object

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a class from an external API and I want to create an instance of it and access that object's methods from different threads.  My questions are as comments in the following code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class ThreadSafetyQuestion {


    static class ExternalAPIObject {
        void method(){

        }
    }

    private static volatile ExternalAPIObject obj;

    static synchronized ExternalAPIObject syncGetObject(){
        return obj;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(()-> {
            ThreadSafetyQuestion.syncGetObject().method();//Is this thread safe?

            ExternalAPIObject externalAPIObject = ThreadSafetyQuestion.syncGetObject();
            //do some other stuff
            externalAPIObject.method();//I doubt this is thread safe.  How can I access this method from multiple threads in a safe way?
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking at this from the wrong perspective. Thread safe means: when more than one thread invokes these methods nothing *bad* happens. It is really simple: when `method()` does manipulate "internal data" without any form of synchronisation - then having more than one thread call `method()` on the same object can result in a problem.

Thus: all the things that you put up in your question do not matter!

The only thing that matters: what *exactly* do these methods do that *you* are invoking?! In other words: there is no point in putting up a singleton to call methods in different threads. Or making the object reference *volatile*. All these ideas add *zero* in regards of making things "thread safe". Because you still allow `method()` to be called on the *same* object by different threads.

What you have to do instead: carefully *check* what exactly the methods you are invoking are doing.

And in case you don't want to go there: then create a single singleton that simply *delegates* calls to `method()` - but that has its methods marked as `synchronized`.

So: if you don't know anything about the external API - then one *conservative* approach is to make sure to **always** all its methods *sequentially*. Of course that can affect performance in very negative ways.

Long story short: it seems you are lacking *basic* understanding of multithreading concepts in Java. Don't go for trial/error then - rather step back and study this topic in depth! Seriously: multi-threading errors are subtle, they often go unnoticed for days or months. The first step in avoiding them: knowing what you are doing (instead of throwing some keywords at a problem that you somehow read about having this or that effect).

Comment: So you're saying I have to wrap each individual method of ExternalAPIObject in a synchronized wrapper method?  Ugh.. Ok, I'll take your advice and study up a bit more on the topic.